# oozie rest api for specific job names aka appname

Tags: hadoop, oozie, oozie-workflow

I am trying to get the workflow info for specific jobs using the Rest API.

```
http://xxxxx:11000/oozie/v1/jobs?appName=oozie_job_1
```

This is returning all the jobs along with oozie_job_1. I want to somehow filter the info shown only to oozie_job_1.

I also tried using
`http://xxxxx:11000/oozie/v1/jobs?filter=appName%3Doozie_job_1` 
but this throws an error.

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing this issue.

I want to get details of a particular workflow/appName from the Oozie Rest API and thus tried to find some documentation/reference about the parameters that we can pass like appName, user etc to the Oozie rest endpoints which could filter down the results in the json from all the workflows running in the Oozie server to the one I want.

As of now there isn't any way in which you can get the data about a particular workflow/appName from Oozie Rest API.

I referred to your post and to the [cloudera](https://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2013/06/how-to-use-the-apache-oozie-rest-api/) and passed `appName` and `user` as param name in the URL but still got all jobs in json.

This problem is also present in ver2 of the API as well.

This issue would slow the program to some seconds as the json content would be big with information of all the appNames that have succeeded/failed/running on the Oozie server on that day. But that is the only option we have now until this is fixed.

The **solution** would be to get the json containing all the workflows and parse it and get the required info.

Hope it helps